# Swift JSON Search Date format by Year-month?

Tags: json, swift, api

I am using Eodhistoricaldata.com's API to get the monthly values of issues.

https://eodhistoricaldata.com/api/eod/VTSMX?from=2017-09-01&api_token=xxxxxx&period=m&fmt=json

And even though it is monthly data they are assigning the first trade date to the results.  -01, -02, -03, etc

This means I can not use a generic date of -01.  So YYYY-MM-01 does not work.

So I either have to change all the dates to -01 or search by just the year and month like  "2017-10"

What is the best way to accomplish this using Swift 4 and SwiftyJSON.

Thanks.

Here is their data.

```
[{"date":"2017-09-01","open":"61.9300","high":63.03,"low":"61.4400","close":63.03,"adjusted_close":61.6402,"volume":0},
{"date":"2017-10-02","open":"63.3400","high":"64.5300","low":"63.3400","close":64.39,"adjusted_close":62.9703,"volume":0},
{"date":"2017-11-01","open":"64.4400","high":66.35,"low":"64.0600","close":66.35,"adjusted_close":64.8872,"volume":0},
{"date":"2017-12-01","open":"66.2100","high":"67.3500","low":"65.7700","close":66.7,"adjusted_close":65.5322,"volume":0},
{"date":"2018-01-02","open":"67.2500","high":"71.4800","low":"67.2500","close":70.24,"adjusted_close":69.0102,"volume":0},
{"date":"2018-02-01","open":"70.2400","high":"70.2400","low":"64.4000","close":67.63,"adjusted_close":66.4458,"volume":0},
....
{"date":"2018-12-03","open":"69.5700","high":"69.5700","low":"58.1700","close":62.08,"adjusted_close":62.08,"volume":0}]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Drop SwiftyJSON and use `Decodable` to parse the JSON into a struct. Parsing dates is highly customizable. You can add your own logic which extracts year and month from the date string and create a `Date` instance.

```
struct HistoricalData: Decodable {
    let date: Date
    let open, low, high : String
    let close, adjustedClose, volume : Double
}

...

let jsonString = """
[{"date":"2017-09-01","open":"61.9300","high":"63.03","low":"61.4400","close":63.03,"adjusted_close":61.6402,"volume":0},
{"date":"2017-10-02","open":"63.3400","high":"64.5300","low":"63.3400","close":64.39,"adjusted_close":62.9703,"volume":0},
{"date":"2017-11-01","open":"64.4400","high":"66.35","low":"64.0600","close":66.35,"adjusted_close":64.8872,"volume":0},
{"date":"2017-12-01","open":"66.2100","high":"67.3500","low":"65.7700","close":66.7,"adjusted_close":65.5322,"volume":0},
{"date":"2018-01-02","open":"67.2500","high":"71.4800","low":"67.2500","close":70.24,"adjusted_close":69.0102,"volume":0},
{"date":"2018-02-01","open":"70.2400","high":"70.2400","low":"64.4000","close":67.63,"adjusted_close":66.4458,"volume":0},
{"date":"2018-12-03","open":"69.5700","high":"69.5700","low":"58.1700","close":62.08,"adjusted_close":62.08,"volume":0}]
"""

let data = Data(jsonString.utf8)

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
decoder.dateDecodingStrategy = .custom { decoder -> Date in
    let container = try decoder.singleValueContainer()
    let dateStr = try container.decode(String.self)
    let components = dateStr.components(separatedBy: "-")
    guard components.count > 2, let year = Int(components[0]), let month = Int(components[1]) else { throw DecodingError.dataCorruptedError(in: container, debugDescription: "Invalid date string") }
    return Calendar.current.date(from: DateComponents(year: year, month: month))!
}
do {
    let result = try decoder.decode([HistoricalData].self, from: data)
    print(result)
} catch { print(error) }
```

---

Alternatively you can decode the string to format `yyyy-MM` however you have to write an initializer and add CodingKeys

```
struct HistoricalData: Decodable {
    let date: String
    let open, low, high : String
    let close, adjustedClose, volume : Double

    private enum CodingKeys : String, CodingKey {
       case date, open, low, high, close, adjustedClose, volume
    }

    init(from decoder: Decoder) throws {
        let container = try decoder.container(keyedBy: CodingKeys.self)
        let dateString = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .date)
        guard let secondDashRange = dateString.range(of: "-", options: .backwards) else {
            throw DecodingError.dataCorruptedError(forKey: .date, in: container, debugDescription: "Invalid date string")
        }
        date = String(dateString[..<secondDashRange.lowerBound])
        open = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .open)
        low = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .low)
        high = try container.decode(String.self, forKey: .high)
        close = try container.decode(Double.self, forKey: .close)
        adjustedClose = try container.decode(Double.self, forKey: .adjustedClose)
        volume = try container.decode(Double.self, forKey: .volume)
    }

}

let data = Data(jsonString.utf8)

let decoder = JSONDecoder()
decoder.keyDecodingStrategy = .convertFromSnakeCase
do {
    let result = try decoder.decode([HistoricalData].self, from: data)
    print(result)
} catch { print(error) }
```

Comment: impressive answer. way about my pay grade and I thank you very much.

Comment: All this because they show the stupid first trade day of month in the month - which is something no one will ever use!  Still looking for the perfect replacement for the Google API.  IEX Beta is not there.  The others just cost too much.  Bummer.

Comment: seriously impressive!  I hope Eodhistoricaldata.com takes a hint.

Comment: I am back to this function and need to update for more protection when using Alamofire.  I can not get this code to work with AF.   I am getting Cannot convert value of type 'DataResponse<Any>' to expected argument type 'Data'

Comment: let data = Alamofire.request(url).responseJSON()

Comment: let url = "https://eodhistoricaldata.com/api/eod/\(symbol).US?from=\(beg)&to=\(end)&api_token=\(EOD_KEY)&period=m&fmt=json"

Comment: You need `.responseData`. The URL is pointless without the API key

Comment: I am getting the data fine.  the API key is there - just cut off by the page here

Comment: .US?from=\(beg)&to=\(end)&api_token=\(EOD_KEY)&period=m&fmt=json"

Comment: just showing code - didnt think good idea to share API key with the world. ;-)

Comment: Please ask a new question and add the code and the issue you got.

Comment: here is a demo link with data from the company

Comment: https://eodhistoricaldata.com/api/intraday/AAPL.US?api_token=OeAFFmMliFG5orCUuwAKQ8l4WWFQ67YX&interval=5m

Comment: Once again please ask a new question. The demo link contains CSV and it's still unclear what your issue is.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work with the API company to overcome this issue with eodhistorical data.

They now have written a special API to get back just the last monthly data - so no more need to write crazy Json code.
There is now a special request for the data using "period = eom"

jsonUrl = "https://eodhistoricaldata.com/api/eod/(symbol).US?from=(beg)&to=(end)&api_token=(EOD_KEY)&period=eom&fmt=json"

this really made live much better.  (After wasting house trying to overcome their data.)